# Why is my dynamically created content not searchable in Google

Tags: ajax, web-crawler

My website provides dynamically created content to be visible to crawlers, based on the following spec:
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification.
This way, Google crawler indexes about 5000 urls with following syntax:
http://www.unclestock.com//app.jsp?_escaped_fragment_=s=AAPL
http://www.unclestock.com//app.jsp?_escaped_fragment_=s=GOOG

Looking to my crawl reports with Google's Webmaster tool, I'm sure these pages are successfully crawled. However, they do not appear as results when searching via Google.
Remark that I do find my general website, and under 'more results', I find about 40 of these dynamically generated pages, but obviously that's not what I want. I want to find the pages back based on their content (AAPL, GOOG, ...)
Perhaps, the crawler considers my pages as more or less the same.. but they are not.

Comment: I was wrong, my pages were not successfully crawled. [this post][1] solved it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122865/servlet-filter-is-not-honoured-for-welcome-file%20solved%20it.

Answer (score 0):

Google would normally only request a page with ?_escaped_fragment_= if it saw a URL with #! in it. The pages will be indexed as #! (so that clicking the link in the Google search result will go to the URL with #!), not indexed as ...escaped_fragment...

You say that Google indexed URLs that had "escaped_fragment" -- but if you quoted them accurately, Google never saw a URL "http://www.unclestock.com/app.jsp?#!s=AAPL" -- if it had, there would have been two ? after app.jsp as #! is replaced by ?#!_escaped_fragment_=

My impression is that jsp code needs to have ? in the URL before the #! so the site wouldn't work as

.../app.jsp#!s=AAPL